# Simple-Framework and Factory Methods

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

Been looking into Simple XML since my project needs are relatively basic, get the general idea, however hit a stumbling block when it comes to classes with no public constructors, that rely on either an in class factory method, or a factory object, to make them, generic ex:

```
public class Foo
{
    private static HashMap<String,Foo> fooTypes = new HashMap<String,Foo>();

    private String name;
    private int val;
    private Foo(String name, int val)
    {
         // do things
    }

    public static Foo getFoo(String name)
    {
         // Store deep copy of fooTypes.get(name) into foo
         return fooResult;
    }

    public static void addFoo(String name)
    {
         fooTypes.put(name, new Foo(name,0));
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to annotate this in Simple XML for it to know to call getFoo when reading xml to objects, or am I out of luck? I suppose I could convert all the code to avoid the Factory pattern, but that doesn't feel like the right answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at @Resolve and @Replace they can call methods on the class to product the instance.

Comment: They both execute after Persistor has already tried to look for a constructor though. Unless I'm missing something here, it still looks like there doesn't seem to be anything that can fill in for there being no public constructor available, except possibly using a Converter to overwrite the normal serialization/deserialization processes entirely. Which starts to rapidly make framework not much of a replacement for lengthier xml conversion code...